# Making an Angular Material data table rows scroll while maintaining a sticky a header

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

[Stack Blitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zaobfh)

I am having trouble figuring out how to get my code to behave as needed.

As the demo shows I have a table that when the add button is clicked a new row is added. Once the table rows reach a certain height (say for example after adding 5 rows) I need a vertical scroll bar to display and at the same time I need to maintain a sticky header. Basically I need to set the table rows to a fixed height.

The attached screen shot shows where I would like the scroll bar to display. Apologies for the shaky highlight.

The HTML looks looks like this

```
<div class="table-container">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Category</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let code" >
        <mat-form-field class="code">
          <mat-select>
            <mat-option *ngFor=" let category of categories" [value]="category.code" class="dropdownpPopUp"  (keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown()">{{category.code}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Type</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let code" >
        <mat-form-field class="type">
          <mat-select >
            <mat-option *ngFor=" let type of types" [value]="type.code" class="dropdownpPopUp"  (keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown()">{{type.code}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="additionalCode" class="parent" >
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Additional Code</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="parent" >
        <mat-form-field class="type">
          <input matInput (keyup)="toggleLookup($event)" autocomplete="off" (keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown()">
        </mat-form-field>
        <div *ngIf="expanded" class="child">Yah it expanded
          <button (click)="expanded = false">Close</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ref">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Reference</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="element.type"  (keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown()" autocomplete="off">
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="add">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="addRow()" matTooltip="Add Row">
          <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let code; let i = index;">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="removeAt(i)" matTooltip="Remove Row">
          <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let rows; columns: columns;"></tr>
  </table>
   <div *ngIf="dataSource.filteredData.length > 0" > <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5]" showFirstLastButtons class="paginator"></mat-paginator></div>
</div>
```

Component Add Function

```
addRow() {
    this.doAddRow();
    this.expanded = false;
  }
  private doAddRow() {
    ELEMENT_DATA.push({ code: '', type: '', reference: '' });
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: please add here some of your code and not only link(the link can removed and in future other user won't understand your question )

Comment: Updated as requested

Answer (score 2):

> what you have to do is add a `div` outside of your table and provide a
>   `min-height` property.

**app.component.css**

```
.main-table{
  max-height:42vh;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ol>
  <li>Select + to add rosw</li>
</ol> 
<p>After 5 new rows added a vertical scroll bar should aprear and when srolling the header row should still be visible</p>
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="main-table">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Category</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let code" >
        <mat-form-field class="code">
          <mat-select>
            <mat-option *ngFor=" let category of categories" [value]="category.code" class="dropdownpPopUp"  (keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown()">{{category.code}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Type</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let code" >
        <mat-form-field class="type">
          <mat-select >
            <mat-option *ngFor=" let type of types" [value]="type.code" class="dropdownpPopUp"  (keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown()">{{type.code}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="additionalCode" class="parent" >
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Additional Code</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="parent" >
        <mat-form-field class="type">
          <input matInput (keyup)="toggleLookup($event)" autocomplete="off" (keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown()">
        </mat-form-field>
        <div *ngIf="expanded" class="child">Yah it expanded
          <button (click)="expanded = false">Close</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ref">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Reference</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="element.type"  (keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown()" autocomplete="off">
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="add">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="addRow()" matTooltip="Add Row">
          <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let code; let i = index;">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="removeAt(i)" matTooltip="Remove Row">
          <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let rows; columns: columns;"></tr>
  </table>
  </div>
   <div *ngIf="dataSource.filteredData.length > 0" > <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5]" showFirstLastButtons class="paginator"></mat-paginator></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Angular Material [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sticky-rows-and-columns) has covered that.

> By using position: sticky styling, the table's rows and columns can be
>   fixed so that they do not leave the viewport even when scrolled. The
>   table provides inputs that will automatically apply the correct CSS
>   styling so that the rows and columns become sticky.

You just need to make the following changes to your `<tr>` tag with the `mat-header-row` directive.

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns; sticky: true"></tr>
```

In addition, you will need to edit your container class around your table to include the following properties:

```
.table-container {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  /*
  other CSS properties
   */
}
```

This will allow your material datatable to have a sticky header. Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lmgjbpdlexve?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-header-example.ts) provided by the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that and you're quite right that's how the official documentation shows describes how to accomplish this generally. However, Its not quite how I would like my table to render. I have added a screen shot describing were I would like the scroll bar to be displayed. I'm hoping its possible.